# How to find out which of my deleted answers were also accepted?

Tags: support

The question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65854898/10819573 for which I had posted an answer got deleted after 10 days. My answer was the accepted one. However, it does not show the **Accepted** icon anymore after it was deleted.

[image]

I want to find such accepted answers and post them to other questions (e.g. duplicate targets). The answers which were accepted as well as upvoted can be easily recognized but I am unable to recognize the answers which were accepted, did not get any upvote, and got deleted later.

How can I find out which of my deleted answers were also accepted?

Comment: why do you want such information?

Comment: @yivi - Thanks, but it does not return any result.

Comment: Maybe deleted answers get unaccepted. Would make sense.

Comment: @yivi - Yes, it looks like that is the case and therefore I posted this question. Maybe it's a basic question, but I've been active on SO for just 18 months, and therefore I am not aware of many things. I searched for an answer to this problem but I could not find one.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to find out on your own reputation page? If it was accepted, I'd expect you'd have an entry on that day for the 15 reputation points. I believe you need to choose to see deleted posts for it to show.

Comment: Scratte - My reputation page has 17 tabs and therefore it will be a tedious task  to expand all days and find it out in such a way (not sure even it is possible this way ). @yivi posted a query, `user:me isaccepted:yes deleted:yes` in his comment (which he has deleted now) which looked very promising but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @Scratte - I just checked my reputation page, specifically for the question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65854898/10819573 but there is no trace.

Comment: Yes, I believe the system removes the checkmark on deletion. I can't see deleted posts, but check the timeline on one that you know you had an accepted post on and see if the checkmark shows [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVKYz.png). There's also [the "raw" reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) where you can look for event type 1. Then you can paste the id after "stackoverflow.com/q/" (it will load the Answer, even if you put a q there.) Or search for the Answer id on the raw reputation page :)

Comment: how do you get 42 upvotes for such an answer, i become rarely more than one.

Comment: Looking at the raw reputation page, I'm no longer sure that it would show. I have a few "User was removed", but I can't seem to find those entries on that page.

Comment: @nbk - I do not understand what you want to prove by demeaning those who upvoted the answer. Please comment or answer if you know the solution.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinashi wasonly wandering about the upvotes of the hole question and answer, that looks more than fishy, i doubt there is such a possibility tochekc which deleted answers where acccepted,but when i loose 420points,i would noticeit and look why this is

Comment: @nbk -Check [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405201/10819573) which shows how to find which answer for a particular question is the `Accepted` answer. The requirement here is to find all my deleted answers which were also accepted. Regarding your remark, `...looks more than fishy...`, you've been active on SO for almost three times longer than I am and therefore I expect that you should check the timeline of the question and its answers before posting such hostile messages.

Comment: @Scratte - Thank you for the suggestions. The accepted answer has finally worked.

Comment: (The question was deleted due to plagiarism (which *seems* to become more or more rampant). Quote *"It seems the poster has simply posted a code snippet from a known bug without stating that they've done this (and changing some details to obfuscate this fact)."*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't directly find that out in the UI. But if you have the postid of either your answer or the question it is on and plug it into a query on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, magic can happen.

The votes table holds accept votes on answers (votetypeid = 1). [The votes table still holds the vote records for deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355095/158100). Most other tables don't.

Because we're talking about deleted posts we can't use the Posts table but need to use PostsWithDeleted. That table includes deleted posts but only has [a limited fields populated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100).

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1373569?postid=65854898) returns a link to an accepted answer that on clicking puts the focus on your answer.

```sql
select concat('site://q/', pwd.id, '| Accepted Answer ', pwd.id) [Link]
from votes v
inner join postswithdeleted pwd on pwd.id = v.postid
where (pwd.id = ##postid?65854898## -- or 65858840
or pwd.parentid = ##postid?65854898##)
and votetypeid = 1 -- accept
```

So using the above query allows you to find out which answer on a deleted question was accepted.

If you want to process 50 postids at once use the second query and these steps:

- [Search for your deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1&searchOn=3)
- Open the developer console of your browser
- Paste below code block and hit enter

  ```
  (function() { 
     var ids = []; 
     $('.result-link a').each((a,c) => {
       var b = $(c); 
       ids.push(Number.parseInt(b.attr('href').split('/')[2]));
     }); 
     console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  })();
  ```
- Goto SEDE, Fork [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1373569?postid=65854898) and copy the result from the developer console (the [1,2,3] bit) in the @json variable (fork the query first)

  ```
  declare @json nvarchar(max)
  -- paste the result from your console here between the ' '
  set @json = '[42, 1337]'

  select concat('site://q/', pwd.id, '| Accepted Answer ', pwd.id) [Link]
  from votes v
  inner join postswithdeleted pwd on pwd.id = v.postid
  inner join OpenJson(@json) sel on (sel.value = pwd.id or sel.value = pwd.parentid)
  where votetypeid = 1 -- accept
  and pwd.deletiondate is not null
  ```
- Run and find the result in the second result tab(click the 2 in the  result tab)
- repeat for all pages in the search result

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Thanks for posting the query (deserves +1). As you have already mentioned, it shows which answer for a particular question is the `Accepted` answer. However, I want to know all my deleted answers which were also accepted.

Comment: The first script worked well but the second one results in some error ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/bYmMqzr))

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash it worked perfectly. You only copied too much in the dev console. There is one code block after *Paste below code block and hit enter* and then a new instruction for you to follow.

Comment: I was able to understand my mistake after going through your updated answer. It worked like a charm! I have got 61 results after executing the query!

Comment: rene - A few of the links in the result point to the accepted answer of someone else. Out of curiosity, is it possible to filter just my answers? Given the number of downvotes and hostile messages, I do not want to post another question in meta  for this. It looks like some folks did not like the question referencing the answer which has got 42 upvotes . However, I did not reference that question/answer intentionally; it's by default, the first result on the page which shows all my deleted answers.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash no, it is not possible to find only your deleted answers because PostsWithDeleted doesn't have the owneruserid set for deleted posts. I linked to the MSE post that explains what is available for deleted posts. Even knowing the accept vote on an answer is already kind of an hack. For non-deleted posts you would simply look for a match on the acceptedanswerid.